# Why does my html request doesn't contain all elements displayed on my navigator?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm learning to **scrape** and I tried to **scrape** this booking page:

https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaE2IAQGYAQ24ARjIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgS4Asn-2-kFwAIB&sid=a454e37209591e054b02e8917d61befe&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.fr.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaE2IAQGYAQ24ARjIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgS4Asn-2-kFwAIB%3Bsid%3Da454e37209591e054b02e8917d61befe%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Paris&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Paris&ssne_untouched=Paris&dest_id=-1456928&dest_type=city&checkin_year=2019&checkin_month=7&checkin_monthday=28&checkout_year=2019&checkout_month=7&checkout_monthday=29&group_adults=1&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1

While a curl command does not work (I got some error I don't understand...) I had to use a proxy service provider online via their API to make my request. This way, I get my html response but it doesn't contain prices and instead displays "voir les tarifs" buttons.
Can anyone explain to me why is it so ? I guess it has to do with script and dynamic displaying ...
Thank you for your time !

Comment: What does that error you don't understand **say**?

Comment: I have something like  error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.fr.html%3Flabel ...